# Pass text parameter to the url variable at .load function on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, parameters, load

I am trying to pass a text by parameter (with whitespaces) to the load function and it seems it doesn't work.

Currently i am doing this:

```
var text ="hello world this is an example";
$("#selector").load("http://"+ document.domain + "/myfunction/"+text);
```

Is there any way to do it?

If i call the function by URL directly, not with jQuery, it works well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should encode "text" with encodeURI:

```
var text = encodeURI('hello world this is an example');
```

This will ensure that your whitespaces are replaced with url compatible characters, which your browser does internally when you're directly accessing the url.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the function by URL directly might works well in your browser. But it is not future proof. You must encode your url with `encodeURI` function. After appending user given data.

```
var text ="hello world this is an example",
url = encodeURI("http://"+ document.domain + "/myfunction/"+ text);
$("#selector").load(url);
```

And on server side you can do something like this to get back user entered data.

```
$data = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// This will return
// /myfunction/hello world this is an example
```